# AutoHotkey warns that a local variable has the same name as a global variable

Tags: global-variables, autohotkey, compiler-warnings

Any time I try accessing a global variable from an AutoHotkey function with `#warn` enabled, I'm shown a warning prompt saying my local variable has the same name as a global variable.

This warning only seems to affect functions. Accessing the variable from a hotstring doesn’t raise any warnings.

```
#Warn
myString := "Hello, world!"

DisplayString() {
   MsgBox %myString%   ; Warning: local variable
}

^j::
   MsgBox, %myString%  ; Perfectly valid!
Return
```

Why can't I access global variables from a function when warnings are enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `#Warn`, global variables should be explicitly declared as global to prevent ambiguity. This can be done in one of three ways.

**Declare the variable as global prior to use**

```
myString := "Hello, world!"
DisplayString()
{
    global myString  ; specify this variable is global
    MsgBox %myString%
}
```

**Assume-global mode inside the function**

```
myString := "Hello, world!"
DisplayString()
{
    global  ; assume global for all variables accessed or created inside this function
    MsgBox %myString%
}
```

**Use a super-global variable**

```
global myString := "Hello, world!" ; global declarations made outside a function
                                   ; apply to all functions by default
DisplayString()
{
    MsgBox %myString%
}
```

For more information about global variables, [refer to the official AutoHotkey documentation](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#Global).

Comment: A couple clarifications: `#Warn` only warns you about possible errors, variables you use inside functions only need to be declared as global if that's what you want. Another possibility to eliminate the warning is to explicitly define it as local `local myString := "Hello, local world!"`

Comment: Is there any way to limit the scope of variables inside a hotkey or hotstring? I get an error when I try to define those as local.

Comment: No, this is only relevant to functions. You can call a function from a hotkey.